# Duplicate frameworks when switching from CocoaPods to Swift Package Manager

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I'm updating an Xcode project from using CocoaPods for GoogleMobileAds to Swift Package Manager (SPM). Since GoogleMobileAds and Firebase both use GoogleUtils, I also need to move Firebase to SPM. Once I got my project to build, I get the following error when running it:

```
Simulator device returned an error for the requested operation.
Domain: IXUserPresentableErrorDomain
Code: 1
Failure Reason: Please try again later.
Recovery Suggestion: Found bundle at /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2A3A1CD2-8D01-412F-9477-FD2B3BFE9097/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.4kpWUf/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestore_-292466A984E2FA1B_PackageProduct.framework with the same identifier (FirebaseFirestore) as bundle at /Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/2A3A1CD2-8D01-412F-9477-FD2B3BFE9097/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.4kpWUf/extracted/MyApp.app/Frameworks/FirebaseFirestore.framework
User Info: {
    DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-11-10 01:50:10 +0000";
    IDERunOperationFailingWorker = IDELaunchiPhoneSimulatorLauncher;
    SimCallingSelector = "installApplication:withOptions:error:";
}
```

So there are 2 copies of `FirebaseFirestore.framework` getting copied into my application framework directory, one with the name `FirebaseFirestore.framework` and the other with the name `FirebaseFirestore_-292466A984E2FA1B_PackageProduct.framework`. Going through my project it is not obvious why this is happening, but it is happening in the same step `Build target FirebaseFirestore with configuration MyConfig`.

Comment: If you create a new project with SPM and add the two (GoogleMobileAds & Firebase), do you still encounter the issue? Are there remaining Pods in your project?